# Prove that if $S$ is a nonempty set of real numbers then $x$ in $\overline{S}$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$.

Tags: real-analysis

The following is typed class notes.

> Lemma $3.15 (c)$. For every point $x \in S$, there exists $\epsilon> 0$ $s.t.$ $N(x,\epsilon)$ $\subset S$
>
> Lemma $3.20$. If $S$ is a nonempty set of real numbers then $x$ in $\overline{S}$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$. This is also equivalent to saying that every open set containing $x$ contains at least one point in $S$.
>
> $proof.$ Recall that $\overline{S}=S\cup Bd(S)$. If $x$ in S then the conditions on both sides of the first 'iff' are clearly true.

But it's the second part of the proof where I start to get confused.

> On the other hand, if $x\notin S$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S^{c}$, namely $x$, and so in this case: $x \in \overline{S}$ iff $x \in Bd(S)$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$.

Okay, so I get why $x \in \overline{S}$ iff $x \in Bd(S)$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$.

> The $\leftarrow$ direction of the last assertion (follows? some word is missing and I'm guessing it's follows) from the first 'iff', since any neighborhood is open. For the other direction, if $U$ is an open set containing $x$, then by Lemma 3.15(c), $U$ contains a neighborhood of $x$, which contains at least one point in $S$. QED

It's this part that confuses me. I know it says last assertion, but are we talking about Lemma 3.20? I was wondering if someone could perhaps reword this part because I'm pretty lost when it comes to proving Lemma 3.20

Comment: Why don't you tell us the definition of $\overline S?$

Comment: It's closure of a nonempty set $S$

Comment: I figured it was the closure. It is really hard to try to answer your question without knowing HOW THE CLOSURE OF A SET IS DEFINED IN YOUR CLASS. For me, the closure of a set $S$ is the set of all points $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S.$ I'm guessing you are working with some other definition.

Comment: ??? The exact same definition is written in the notes I've posted above. The only thing I failed to explicitly mention was that $S$ with a bar over it denotes closure of the set $S$.

Comment: Sharon, how is boundary defined in your class?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: I'm sure you can google it. Is there some sort of conceptual shortcoming? I'm just not getting it.

Comment: ??? So $\overline S$ is defined as "the set of all points $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$"? And the Lemma whose proof you're having trouble with says that "$x$ in $\overline S$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $S$"? Why are you trying to prove a definition?

Comment: @bof: To answer your first question, yes. obviously. That's why we have "iff."  To answer your second question, I'm trying to prove a lemma. If you don't know how to answer the question I've posted, then by all means don't waste my time.

Comment: Sharon. Both bof and Antoine are capable and willing to help you. The problem is you haven't defined what closure and boundary mean to you. Both of these terms have many equivalent definitions, so unless you state precisely which definitions you are working with, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Is $S=S\cup Bd(S)$ a typo for $\overline S=S\cup Bd(S)$?

Comment: @JohnGriffin: I appreciate your input. Unfortunately, I'd argue that bof did not seem to read the definition written above. It is clearly stated how the closure of the set is defined. I'd also argue that one does not need the word-for-word definiton. If one deeply understands the material, then answering the question can easily be done.

Comment: @Sharon The only hint at a definition I see is $S=S\cup Bd(S)$, which appears to be a typo for $\overline{S}=S\cup Bd(S)$. This definition is fine as long as you also define $Bd(S)$, which you failed to do. One does need the word-for-word definition if we are to know where you are having issues and how to resolve them. We all know what the closure and boundary mean. We don't know what they mean to you.

Comment: @JohnGriffin: read the second pink-highlighted part. I've edited that typo btw. Other than that, this conversation is going nowhere of importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is in $\overline S$ then $x$ is in $S$ or on the boundary of $S$. If $x$ is in $S$ then every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point from $S$ (it contains at least $x$) and if $x$ is on the boundary of $S$, then, from the definition of the boundary we also have that every neigborhood of $x$ contains at least one point from $S$.

If every  neighborhood of $x$ contain at least one point from $S$ then $x$ must be in $\overline S$. Why? The only place where $x$ can be is either $\overline S$ or the complement of $\overline S$. Suppose that $x$ is in the complement of $\overline S$. Then there exists neighborhood of $x$ that does not contain points from $\overline S$. That means such a neighborhood does not contain points neither from $S$ nor from the boundary of $S$, but that is a contradiction with the assumption that every  neighborhood of $x$ contain at least one point from $S$ so $x$ is not in the complement of $\overline S$, so $x$ is in $\overline S$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof has two cases. The first case is if $x\in S$, and you claimed you are fine with it. Let's focus in on the $x\not\in S$ case. We have the following equivalence, which you also claim to understand:
$$
x\in\overline{S} \iff x\in Bd(S) \iff \text{every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$}.
$$
Simplifying this equivalence, we obtain
$$
x\in\overline{S} \iff \text{every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$}.
$$
This is precisely the statement of Lemma $3.20$, excluding the last line.

For the last line, we prove
\begin{align*}
&\text{every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$} \\
&\iff 
\text{every open set containing $x$ contains at least one point of $S$}.
\end{align*}
The $\implies$ direction is trivial because every open set containing $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. For the $\impliedby$ direction, suppose $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Then there is an open set $V$ such that $x\in V \subseteq U$. By our assumption $V$ contains a point in $S$, so $U$ does as well.